# Como executar um Webservice WSDL a partir de uma Stored Procedure do SQL Server

Tags: sql

Alguem sabe como criar uma procedure do SQL Server para executar um Webservice do fluig ?

A idéia é criar um processo a partir da execução da Procedure

Lí sobre as Ole Automation Stored Procedures do SQL Server mas estou com dúvidas sobre como devo monta-las  pois preciso passar a URL

```
http://SERVIDOR/webdesk/ECMWorkflowEngineService?wsdl'
```

e o XML

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.workflow.ecm.technology.totvs.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:simpleStartProcess>
         <username>usuario</username>
         <password>senha</password>
         <companyId>1</companyId>
         <processId>processo</processId>
         <comments>GERADO VIA WS</comments>
         <attachments>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <item>
               <attachmentSequence>?</attachmentSequence>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <attachments>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <attach>?</attach>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <descriptor>?</descriptor>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <editing>?</editing>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <fileName>?</fileName>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <fileSelected/>
                  <fileSize>?</fileSize>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <filecontent>cid:702686015833</filecontent>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <fullPatch>?</fullPatch>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <iconPath>?</iconPath>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <mobile>?</mobile>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <pathName>?</pathName>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <principal>?</principal>
               </attachments>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <colleagueId>?</colleagueId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <colleagueName>?</colleagueName>
               <companyId>?</companyId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <crc>?</crc>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <createDate>?</createDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <createDateTimestamp>?</createDateTimestamp>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <deleted>?</deleted>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <description>?</description>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <documentId>?</documentId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <documentType>?</documentType>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <fileName>?</fileName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <newAttach>?</newAttach>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <originalMovementSequence>?</originalMovementSequence>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <permission>?</permission>
               <processInstanceId>?</processInstanceId>
               <size>?</size>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <version>?</version>
            </item>
         </attachments>
         <cardData>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <item>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>codigoProduto</item>
               <item>"Item"</item>
            </item>
         </cardData>
      </ws:simpleStartProcess>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Alguem tem ideia de como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não seja melhor método para chamar um WSDL, mas acredito que o exemplo abaixo deva funcionar para você:

```
DECLARE @obj int,
        @url VarChar(MAX),
        @response VarChar(MAX),
        @requestHeader VarChar(MAX),
        @requestBody VarChar(MAX)

SET @url = 'http://....'

SET @requestBody = '<soapenv:Envelope>
                     <soapenv:Header/>
                      <soapenv:Body>
                       ...
                      </soapenv:Body>
                     </soapenv:Envelope>'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'SOAPAction', 'POST'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Length', LEN(@requestBody)
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', NULL, @requestBody
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT


SELECT @response [RESPONSE]

EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

Aqui nesse  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213278/calling-a-soap-webservice-from-tsql-stored-procedure) do StackOverflow, você pode encontrar outras alternativas e adaptar para 
o seu problema.